# Perl regex to parse "1,2,3" into array of numbers

Tags: regex, perl, split

I want Perl to check that a string contains exactly a comma-separated list of digits, then split it into an array.  The regex `/^(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*$/)` does the parsing I want, but when I evaluate it in a list context I only get the first and last digits.  I tried `/(?:^|,)(\d+)(?=,|$)/g` to bring the **g** modifier into play to emit multiple matches, but this fails to fully check the syntax, as the example below shows.  So how do I get a fully-anchored regex like the first one to emit an array of multiple matches to `()*`?

```
foreach (@ARGV) {
    #if (my @numbers = /^(\d+)(?:,(\d+))*$/) {
    if (my @numbers = /(?:^|,)(\d+)(?=,|$)/g) {
    print "$_ = (@numbers)\n";
    } else {
    print "$_ isn't a number list!\n";
    }
}
```

Put the above in a file called `numberlist.pl` and run it and you get this:-

```
bash$ perl numberlist.pl 1,2,3 ,1,2,3 1,2,3, a,2,3 1,b,3 1,2,c aa1,2,3zz
1,2,3 = (1 2 3)
,1,2,3 = (1 2 3)
1,2,3, = (1 2 3)
a,2,3 = (2 3)
1,b,3 = (1 3)
1,2,c = (1 2)
aa1,2,3zz = (2)
```

If you uncomment the first `if` and comment the second then you get this:-

```
1,2,3 = (1 3)
```

so the content of the `()` inside the `(?:)` emits a single match, not a list of matches.

I know I could use the first regex to check syntax and then `my @numbers = split /,/` to get the array, but There's More Than One Way To Do That.  I just can't quite see how.  Help!

Comment: Rather than adding this comment to all three answers, I'll add it to the question. You probably **don't** want to use `\d`. Instead use `[0-9]`. `\d` matches all kinds of interesting Unicode digit characters like "٣" and "߃" and "৩" and "୩" and "൩".

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(?:\d+,)*\d+\z/ or die;
my @numbers = /\d+/g;
```

or

```
my @numbers = split /,/;
die if !@numbers;
for (@numbers) {
   die if !/^\d+\z/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only need regex for filtering out non-numbers. `split` is more useful here:

```
for (@ARGV) {
    next unless $_; # Add this to skip processing of blank entries.
    my @l = grep {/^\d+\z/} split /,/;
    print "$_ = (@l)\n";
}
```

As pointed out, this will treat an empty string as an empty list. That may or may not be how you want it to work.

If you don't mind the possibility of a `\n` on the end of an input string, change the `\z` back to a `$` in the pattern.

Comment: It considers an empty string a list of numbers. That might not be desired.

Comment: It may or may not be, but without a stated requirement either way it's just speculation on our part. All the same, I am pretty sure I do not want `\z` to include newlines in my `grep` block.

Comment: Also, there are better ways to guard against empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend separating the validating from the parsing:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

local @ARGV = do {
    no warnings 'qw';
    qw(1,2,3 ,1,2,3 1,2,3, a,2,3 1,b,3 1,2,c aa1,2,3zz);
};

for (@ARGV) {
    if (/^\d+(?:,\d+)*$/) {
        my @numbers = split ',';
        print "Numbers are @numbers\n";
    } else {
        print "NaN = $_\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
Numbers are 1 2 3
NaN = ,1,2,3
NaN = 1,2,3,
NaN = a,2,3
NaN = 1,b,3
NaN = 1,2,c
NaN = aa1,2,3zz
```

However, if you're attached to joining them, then validate using a positive lookahead assertion and capture outside like so:

```
for (@ARGV) {
    if (my @numbers = /\G(?=\d+(?:,\d+)*$)(\d+),?/g) {
        print "Numbers are @numbers\n";
    } else {
        print "NaN = $_\n";
    }
}
```